# Interactive Web Application

Tags: python, export, blend4web

Is it possible to use Blender for creating an interactive Web App, so that you can change some values in HTML form and by clicking a button, apply them to the script /model? 
I downloaded Blend4Web Addon and exporting a scene as HTML works but its static and cant interact with my form

Answer (score 3):

Yes it possible, but in your case you should do this.

Instead exporting scene, you should open blend4web projects manager

[image]

Here you can create a new project

[image]

In projects, blend files are assets, they will be used by script files.

In projects manager you will find blend files, exported scenes as json files and JavaScript files to work with:

[image]

You can edit Script files using any text editor or from project manager:

[image]

here you can find more information about it:
https://www.blend4web.com/en/community/article/341/